# Localizar Arquivo e Substituir palavra em XML ou TXT

Tags: windows, arquivo, batch, linha-de-comando

Olá,

Tenho que criar um script de linha de comando do DOS (Windows), que localiza um ou vários arquivos .xml que estão localizados em um determinado diretório e altere um valor de uma tag, esta tag pode ser fixa, ou seja, sempre irei busca ela e alterar por um valor pré estabelecido.

Diretório - **C:\XML** (neste diretório serão depositados os arquivos gerados pelo sistema para fazer a alteração da tag)

Supomos que ao executar um dir nesse diretório liste três arquivos .xml ( teste1.xml, teste2.xml e teste3.xml), o números de arquivos e os nomes dos mesmos não serão padrão.

Depois de localizar os arquivos todos devem ser verificados para localizar e substituir uma determinada frase(TAG) dentro do arquivo. Exemplo, localiza a tag    `<nome>fulano</nome>` e substitui por `<nome>ciclano</nome>`

Comment: pela linha de comando você não vai conseguir fazer isso. mais fácil utilizar o notepad++, ou, se realmente for necessário, fazer sua própria ferramenta (que também não é complicado)

Comment: Utilize o [FART](https://sourceforge.net/p/fart-it/wiki/Home/) ou [PowerShell](https://ss64.com/ps/replace.html)

Comment: Testei pelo FART (o nomezinho hein) e funcionou perfeitamente. Grato

Comment: dá pra fazer sim por linha de comando
usando o FOR
mas como o amigo já usou o fart32, não há necessidade de eu montar o script.